# How can I rewrite a url by keeping the file name as it is but the parameter being passed should be the folder name?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am passing a name which will be used as the subfolder but the filename remains the same eg foldername/gallery.php?q=new_folder should be new_folder/gallery.php using htaccess.

Attaching the htaccess of what I a trying to do

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(gallery.php)$ $2.php?q=$1 [L]
```

`gallery.php` is the filename and `$1` is basically the `new_folder`. Been struggling with this for quite a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are fairly close. You just need to use `foldername/` in target URI of your rule.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(gallery\.php)$ foldername/$2.php?q=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just added bellow mentioned code in .htaccess. Hope this will help you.

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^foldername/(.*) http://example.com/newfolder/gallery.php?options=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did try it, but still wasn't working. but adding just the `foldername/` before the file name did help .